# Coded UI Test vs. Microsoft UI Automation library

Tags: ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to do UI testing of my complex WPF application. I have come across two libraries for UI Automation:

1. Coded UI Test
2. Microsoft UI Automation Library.

I am confused in above two options. Please let me know where should I use which library?
wanted to know prons and cons of both?

- Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft UI Automation Library Vs Coded UI Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909206/microsoft-ui-automation-library-vs-coded-ui-test)

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the difference between using System.Windows.Automation and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting for WPF UI Test automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620406/what-is-the-difference-between-using-system-windows-automation-and-microsoft-visu)